# I need help dealing with JUnit tests and CDI eventing

Tags: java, cdi, junit4

I need help building a test for my class. This class does a lot and I'm not allowed to refactor it since I don't have the time (at least my company doesn't allot the time for it).

I have to use a fake class but it looks like this:

```
@Inject
    protected ClassZ(ClassA classA, ClassB classB, ClassC classC, 
                     ClassD classD, ClassE classE, ClassF classF, 
                     ClassG classG, ClassH classH, ClassI classI, etc..)

    public void complexMethod()
    {
        // reads from files using classA, does stuff with classB, etc.
    }
```

Mockito doesn't work for me because those classes that are injected do tons of work: reading from files, writing to files, storing an in-memory database, etc. I know, it's bad code, but I'm stuck with *needing* the real instances of my classes. A @Spy annotation still just performs default methods. So, a `boolean readFile` returns `False` everytime.

How can I escape dependency hell? It's taking me forever to @Inject all the dependencies or use `@AdditionalClasses` to list them out. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you're after but if it's JUnit testing with CDI enabled, then take a look at [weld-junit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit). It works with JUnit 4 or 5 and starts Weld before running test, allowing you to specify what should be in the bean archive (or leave it to discovery). Newest version is for CDI 2.0, older were for 1.2 as well. Not sure which one do you run.

This allows you to test in a full-blown CDI environment without mocking it. It may or may not be what you are after. You will still have to load those classes into CL but you can limit the discovery to as small set as the test requires.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But unfortunately, Weld JUnit was failing to grab the required beans. However, I accepted this answer as most environments that use CDI should easily be able to use weld-junit. Mine is just a headache.

Comment: Alright, if you'd like to dig deeper into why it didn't work with weld-junit, feel free to create a GitHub issue with some reproducer code and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. I have an approach. This is NOT recommended, but I needed to get integration tests up and running yesterday. I'm posting this answer in case anyone else is suffering in the same way I am.

I found a workable solution for my JUnit tests thanks to a coworker talking through it. Turns out it's 100% valid to use Weld in your `@Before` method. I'm loading everything with Weld and instantiating them using the `CDI.current().select().get()` call like so:

```
@Before
public void setup()
{
    RuntimeSupport.initializeDefaults();
    Weld weld = new Weld();
    weld.initialize();
    classZ = CDI.current().select(ClassZ.class).get();
}
```

This sometimes will require a manually instantiation of other dependencies:

eg.

```
ClassY classY = CDI.current().select(ClassY.class).get();
classY.toString(); // ugly forced construction
```

This solution is a simple, small, solution in terms of overhead code. It's a massive solution in terms of overhead class loading.

Comment: I added an answer which I think could help you. However, I wonder why do you need to instantiate beans "eagerly" in before method? E.g. why do you use `CDI.current().select(ClassZ.class).get();`? It is true that bean creation is lazy (for normal scoped beans) but that shouldn't get in your way, the beans would simply be created once you first attempt to retrieve `ClassZ`. That is, if you retrieve it via CDI as well!